# Swift Remove uibutton from uiview

Tags: swift

I would like to ask how can I delete a button from my view with Swift ?
on Object-C i did

```
 - (void)Delete:(id)sender{
   NSArray *subviews = [self.view subviews];
   for (UIView *v in subviews) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
        UIButton *button  = (UIButton*)v;
        if (button.tag == self.deleteIndex) {
            [button removeFromSuperview];
            self.CountButton -= 1;}
```

Comment: Did you try using `view.viewWithTag(deleteIndex).removeFromSuperview()`?

Comment: but to do the same in swift ?

Answer (score 4):

Literal translation of the code in your question into Swift:

```
func Delete(sender: AnyObject) {
    let subviews = self.view.subviews as [UIView]
    for v in subviews {
        if let button = v as? UIButton {
            if button.tag == self.deleteIndex {
                button.removeFromSuperview()
                self.CountButton -= 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note the use of the `as?` cast instead of the `isKindOfClass:` check. In Swift, this is a construct you can use to attempt to cast an object to a specific type.  If the object is not of the type, the cast fails (returning `nil`) and the `if` statement does not execute.